# I am trying to match names from Two Dataframes and adding a running score for each person matched

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, matching

I have two data frames, df1 containing Actor Names & A weighted Score, and df2 containing a list of movies with the cast-members.

I want to loop through the df2 movie cast column to see if they are matching with the df1 Actor Names column. Then add their cumulative weighted score from df1 as a NEW column for df2.

[image: df1]
[image: df2]

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the dummy dataframe I created.

[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igPyx.png)

Here is the second dataframe.

[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpG8Q.png)

Now here is the code to loop through every cast member and add their cumulative score.

```
scores_list=[]
for cast in df2["credits"]:
    score=0
    for actor in cast:
        score+=df[df["Actor"]==actor]["Actor Score"].values[0]
    scores_list.append(score)
```

Now finally. Adding the result to the new df2.

```
df2["scores"]=scores_list
df2.head()
```

Here is the final result.
[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leYIx.png)

Comment: Answer looks good,  please also provide the dataframes as code, so that they can be copied if necessary.